# React Router v6 always render "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement router in react-create-app but it always render "/" and showing Home or SignIn page. How can I solve this?

```
function AppRouter({ isLoggedIn, user }) {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
        {isLoggedIn
          ? <Route exact path={"/"} element={<Home user={user}/>} />
          : <Route exact path={"/"} element={<SignIn />} />
        }
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with rendering a route on `path="/"`? Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: No issue with rendering "/" but even if I try to render "/profile", it renders "/"

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't at all as RRDv6 routes *always* exactly matched. Only 1 route should be matched and rendered at-a-time. Are you *sure* you are rendering/serving the latest code in the development server? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the routing issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-pine-9g0es4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That CSB has incomplete code. Have you ensured you copied all code into it *and* saved it?

Comment: I simplified my code, but I think the problem also occur in CSB identically

Comment: Sorry, I meant that some files are empty and the `App` component is the default code that the sandbox starts with.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-payne-5p7hff
This is my first time using CSB, sorry for bothering you.
Is this link also have incomplete codes?

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately the same as the first sandbox.

Comment: How about this https://codesandbox.io/live/3adc88db97d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246106/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a *slight* misunderstanding of how the `HashRouter` works with the UI.

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
import Home from "./Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The `HashRouter` handles routing with a URL hash value, i.e. everything *after* the `"#"` in the URL. If you are trying to render your app and access `"<domain>/"` instead of `"<domain>/#/"` the routing won't work.

For example in your running codesandbox demo, the base URL is `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/"`. At this base URL the hash router isn't really working, and you should really be accessing `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/#/"` instead so the hash router is loaded and the app's internal routing can work.

From `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/#/"` you should be to then navigate to any of your routes, i.e. `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/#/profile"` and `https://5p7hff.csb.app/#/signUp"`.

[image: Edit young-dawn-ejyruw]

If you switch to a different router, like the `BrowserRouter` then the `"/#/"` is no longer used, the router and routes render from `"/"` where the app is running from. The routes would be `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/"`, `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/profile"`, and `"https://5p7hff.csb.app/signUp"`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
By the way, then why we use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter even if it makes kind of dirty URL.

Comment: @부건혁 I've never understood the argument about "ugly URLs". It's just another way to serve up a webapp from a specific server directory. With the hash router all page requests go to the same domain/subdomain/directory, and the hash is ignored by the server (the app uses it). Github works like this if you use it to host your app. With the other routers you'd configure the server to redirect page requests for nested "routes/pages" to the root index.html file so the React app can load and then handle the routing internally.